# Play sound and move image on mouseover

Tags: javascript

I've just come across a very old page on my website that used to work really well.  I had animated gifs of my dog's toys and on mouseover they leapt up and down and played the toy's sound.  The javascript I used is really old and had the EMBED code. The sounds no longer play. Is there a way to recreate a page like this?

I've tried bits of code from Codepen etc.but can't get anything to work.

Comment: Recreate your page in Codepen and share it with us.

Comment: The sounds were probably hosted somewhere and no longer are.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Edit the question to add the source code from your web page in a code pen.

Comment: Sounds like Flash, which is pretty much dead.

Comment: This is the old page on my website.  I recorded the sounds and put them on the server. I drew the images.  http://www.agilitybits.co.uk/games/concert.html

Comment: I've just tried to post the javascript but it's much too long. I'll see if I can recreate it in Codepen

Comment: Here's the codepen. https://codepen.io/Jillity/pen/BgbrEV